# Template Not Found Error: why commented template inclusion is still being processed

Tags: django, django-templates

Django version 2.0.7, 
Python3.6

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>My Own Website via base file</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>


    <!-- {% include 'navbar.html'  %} -->

    {% block content %}
    {% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

The above code throws an error, whereas the following one doesn't.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>My Own Website via base file</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>

    <!-- comment -->

    {% block content %}
    {% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

The only difference is in the content of comment. Could someone explain ? I am using this code template to learn Django and this example of inheritance in templates throws

> TemplateDoesNotExist at /home/** error.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for commenting use django template comments tag {# #}
replace - `<!-- {% include 'navbar.html'  %} -->`
with - `{# {% include 'navbar.html'  %} #}`

Answer (score 1):

Django's template renderer doesn't respect HTML comments for template filters and tags. The renderer treats html comments the same as any other html element. The only way to comment a filter or tag out in a django template is with a django template comment block or comment line.

So what you're seeing in the template that raises an error is that it's trying to find the `navbar.html` template to include it, but it doesn't exist.